# Remove "Single Event page" from Wordpress blog post

Tags: wordpress

At the bottom of the blog page of my site it says "Single event page"

site: http://advancedpainmedical.com/blog/

Any clue on which file to edit or what setting to modify to remove this from showing up?

Comment: the code for that is '<div class="col-md-4  "><div class="menu_categories"><h4 class="widget_h"><span>Single Event Page</span></h4>   <div class="textwidget"><p>This is a single event page with sample content. This layout is suitable for most websites and types of business like gym, kindergarten, health or law related. Event hours component at the bottom of this page shows all instances of this single event. Build-in sidebar widgets shows upcoming events in the selected categories.</p>
</div>'

Comment: That is just the HTML. But where that HTML is generated is the question. Which wordpress php file or option can disable it.